# Edit a merge commit with git rebase

Tags: git, rebase

In Git when I have commits eg. `A - B - C` and I want to edit the `B` commit, I

- use `git rebase -i <A-commit-hash>`,
- in the list I write `edit` command in front of `B` commit,
- git rebase stops right after `B` commit so I can fix anything I want using `git commit --amend`,

  and then I continue using `git rebase --continue`.

As far as I know this is the best practice how to do this. With this method I can edit any commit in the past (as long as it hasn't been pushed to remote branch yet), and moreover with `-p` flag I can even preserve the merges. This is just great.

My current problem is: I did a mistake (typo) on one line in a merge commit (while resolving a conflict when merging two branches).

I'd like to fix it but I don't know how to make `git rebase` to stop at a merge commit. The `git rebase -p -i <blah>` list ignores merge commits, so I cannot write `edit` command in front of it and make the `git rebase` stop there to let me edit it.

Any help please?
I just want to fix this line in the merge commit while preserving all the commits (and merges) after it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

#### Updated answer for 2020:

You can force `git rebase -i` to stop at the merge commit via the `break` command (added in Git 2.20). You can then edit the merge commit as desired via `git commit --amend`.

Detailed steps:

1. Run `git rebase -i --rebase-merges $ancestor_of_merge_commit`
2. Find the merge commit you want to edit in the todo list.
3. Insert a new line after the merge commit that contains only `break` (or `b`).
4. Save your changes and exit your editor. Git rebase will check out the merge commit, print something like the following, then return you to your prompt:

   ```
   Stopped at fb91fab (Merge branch 'foo' into bar)
   ```
5. Use `git commit --amend` to edit the merge commit as desired.
6. Run `git rebase --continue` when you are done editing the merge commit.

Alternative approach if you do not have any merge commits after the commit you want to edit:

1. Run `git rebase -i $id_of_merge_commit`
2. Insert a new line at the top of the todo list that contains only `break` (or `b`).
3. Save your changes and exit your editor. Git rebase will check out the merge commit, print something like the following, then return you to your prompt:

   ```
   Stopped at fb91fab (Merge branch 'foo' into bar)
   ```
4. Use `git commit --amend` to edit the merge commit as desired.
5. Run `git rebase --continue` when you are done editing the merge commit.

#### Original answer from 2012 (pre-`break`):

Git does not make it easy to do interactive rebases when merges are involved.  The `-p` option uses the `-i` mechanism internally, so mixing the two doesn't really work.

However, `git rebase` is just an automated way to do lots of cherry-picks.  You can replicate its behavior by manually cherry-picking to get a bit more control over the process.  It's less convenient and more prone to human error, but possible.

This is the approach I suggest:

1. use `git rebase` to get to the commit *after* the merge (the child of the merge)
2. use `git reset --hard HEAD^` to manually get to the merge
3. use `git commit --amend` to repair the merge
4. use `git cherry-pick` to get back to the commit after the merge
5. use `git rebase --continue` to finish

Here are the specific steps:

1. Note the SHA1 ID of the merge commit you want to modify.  For discussion, suppose it is `deadbeef`.
2. Note the SHA1 ID of the commit right after the merge commit you want to modify (the merge commit's child).  Suppose it is `facef00d`.
3. Run `git rebase -i deadbeef`.
4. Select `facef00d` for editing.
5. When rebase returns you to a prompt to edit `facef00d`, run `git reset --hard HEAD^`.  You should now be at `deadbeef` (`git rev-parse HEAD` should print `deadbeef`).
6. Make your edits to fix the incorrect merge conflict and use `git add` to stage them.
7. Run `git commit --amend` to fuse the staged fix with the bad merge commit.  The result will now have a different SHA1 (not `deadbeef`).
8. Run `git cherry-pick facef00d` to apply the changes made by `facef00d` to the fixed merge commit.
9. Run `git rebase --continue` to finish.

Comment: Nice. I don't mean the process, but the description. :D

Comment: So basically I get to the `facef00d` with `git rebase`, then I get to the `deadbeef` _manually_, fix what I need, and get back to `facef00d` to finish the rebasing.
I was googling this for a few hours and found nothing. Thanks!

Comment: @vsechnech:  Exactly.  I like your high-level description, so I modified my answer to include it.

Comment: Nice! Note that one simple way of noting the SHA1 values is to make temporary branches or tags at them.

Comment: `git reset --hard` carries the risk of destroying uncommitted work. Can you do this without the hard reset?

Comment: @Cuadue: `rebase` refuses to run if there is uncommitted work, so there is no risk of destroying uncommitted work if you follow this procedure.

Comment: It is error-prone, but actually pretty safe: if I screwed up in any step before the last, I can always get back with `git rebase --abort` and start over. I just need to double-check (very carefully) *right before* the last step.

Comment: Can't steps 1,2 and 4 be avoided by using break before the first commit?
Basically, ``git rebase -i merge-commit-sha``, then b at the very top, then amend the merge commit and ``git rease --continue``.

Comment: Great answer, when it works. I just had one (admittedly rare) scenario where this was horribly inefficient, and added an answer with an easy workaround.

Comment: Your 2020 edit is pretty much a copy of my answer.

Answer (score 13):

This is much easier now with the `--rebase-merges` option available in Git 2.22 and above. This option preserves the merge topology, and works with interactive rebases.

It'll look something like this, assuming `B` is the merge commit to amend:

```
label onto

... some branch definitions ...

reset onto
merge -C B branch-name # Merge branch 'B' into whatever
pick C
```

You can now insert a `b` (or `break`) in between the `merge` and the `pick`:

```
merge -C B branch-name # Merge branch 'xyz' into whatever
break
pick C
```

At the break `commit --amend` the merge, and then continue the rebase.

This also works with a fixup commit. For example, lets say the commit with the fix for the merge is `D`. You can move your fixup commit D to immediately after the merge commit:

```
merge -C B branch-name # Merge branch 'xyz' into whatever
fixup D
pick C
```

See the [Rebasing Merges](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_rebasing_merges) section of the git-merge man page.

Answer (score 1):

May be easier to create a fixup commit 'D' then use '`git rebase -p -i <blah>`' to reorder 'D' right after 'B' and squash it into 'B'.

```
pick A
pick B  <- merge commit to ammend
fixup D
pick C
```

Comment: _I don't know how to make `git rebase` to stop at a merge commit_ is the OPs issue, and mine also. The method you described was my first approach, but I could not get the merge commit to show up in the list to pick.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr:** Sometimes you simply shouldn't use `git rebase` to edit a merge commit. Another method may be more efficient.

I just lived through one such scenario: I had a merge commit which was merging in a very old branch, and there were many conflicts that were resolved in the merge commit. There were some additional commits after the merge, and then it was discovered that a mistake was made in the large merge commit during one file's conflict resolution. I setup the interactive rebase as described in the accepted answer, but when my machine locked up at 2/59 I realized it was writing a **lot** of files due to re-organizing my file system to match the old branch. After a few minutes I killed it, aborted the rebase, then had to delete 100K files to get back to where I started. Instead of rebase I did this instead:

1. Make note of the commit IDs I want to replay after I fix the merge commit.
2. `git reset --hard [merge-commit-id]`
3. Make the change and simply amend the HEAD commit (which is the merge commit).
4. Cherry pick each of the commit IDs in order after the merge commit, or use `git rebase --onto` with 3 arguments to cherry pick the entire range if there are more than just a few.)

This was *much* faster.