# How to git rebase when the commit history is not straight but merged from several programmer

Tags: git, rebase

I have a commit history like:
[image], and I want it to be something like [image]. **EDIT**: history starts at bottom, on top are newer commits.

I'd like to `rebase/squash` all these commits onto "here". Or the one just before "here" is also acceptable.

**EDIT:** What I did were:

1. I'm now at commit "A"
2. `git rebase -i here`
3. set the words to "squash", leaving the first "pick" unchanged
4. it said `error: could not apply c148 ...`.

And it's strange that right after step 2, the editor popped-up from `git rebase` only listed the commits on the blue line, commits on the red line is not there.

How should I fix this?

PS: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9958215/707580) may be useful. Could anyone do a graphic explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Your history starts at the top? Rebasing your branch to "here" should work. Maybe you should skip the two already merged commits.

If this will not work, we need more details. Especially which commit in you picture is c148...

---

In relation to your link you might also just create a new branch at "here" and cherry-pick your four remaining commits of you feature branch.

---

**Edit:**

As you want to squash all your commit beyond "here" you have to checkout your master branch (or whatever the other branch is) and rebase it interactively onto "here". Pick "s" for squash in the editor.

```
git checkout master
git rebase -i here
```

---

P.S.Sorry for adding a answer, just spend all my reputation for my own question and am no longer allowed to comment.

Comment: history starts at bottom. I think cherry-pick is the solution, can you explain it more?

Comment: Your commits already starting at "here" so what do you want to rebase? Can you please create a picture of what you are expecting after the rebase.

Comment: I want to "squash" the commits into kind of straight line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use interactive rebase like this:

```
git rebase -i here^
```

In the editor that pops up change the text `pick` in front of every commit to `s`. Leave only the top commit (`here`) unchanged - it needs to have `pick`.

Comment: @hbrlovehaku: Error messages are no secrets, so no need to keep it secret... In other words: *What error did you get?*

Comment: It said `error: could not apply c148 performance and percentage 80%` which is the commit message. I thought it was useless.

Comment: @hbrlovehaku: It should have said a lot more. For example that you have to resolve the conflict and afterwards continue with `git rebase --continue`.

Answer (score 0):

Rebasing merge commits would be a boring thing. I think `git reset` will be more convenient.

Try this:

```
git reset --hard A
git reset --soft here
git commit -m -C here  // assume this is new-A
```

As you said in comment, suppose you have several new commits after A, and is now at `B` in `master` branch.

Then you can do the following:

```
git rebase --onto new-A A B
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's I was expecting. But I have newer commits after A and I do not want to drop those. I only want the commits between here and A being "squashed". How is that?