# Merging git branch A into branch B once again after the first merge has been reverted

Tags: git, merge

My situation is presented below.

```
              o---o---o issue-2 
             /         \
o---o---o---o---M---R---o develop
         \     /
          o---o---F issue-1
```

There was some work on issue-1. After review, it was merged into develop (commit M). Unfortunately, it was soon discovered that there were some serious errors present. For the sake of other issues the merge commit was reverted (commit R). Later, other issues (like issue-2) were also merged into develop. The code on the original branch was fixed (commit F).

The problem is - how to merge issue-1 into develop now? The simple merge would keep the effect of revert commit R and only apply changes that are not already in develop branch (commit F), not all of them.

Comment: You should be able to revert the revert commit. Great diagram, btw.

Comment: Obviously, but that means even more dirty stuff on the supposedly-clean develop branch. Is there really no other way?

Comment: Or you can try squashing `M` and `R` (if no one else has `develop` checked out...)

Comment: develop is a public branch, lots of people working on it; the situation is already bad, modifying develop history is rather a no-go

Comment: then you should do the revert revert, I think

Comment: There are lots of solutions. You could make a new issue branch off of the head of `develop`, apply the code there (using patches, for example), and merge that in. You could also use interactive rebasing to delete the revert commit from your history.

Comment: I will stick with the new issue solution then. On the other hand, I started to wonder whether the question is valid or should be deleted as an subjective one?

Comment: I think it is a very valid question for a common workflow in git managed source codes. Also I would find the revert revert solution the most githonic way to do it ;)

Comment: I think I would revert the revert commit (call it `R2`), then squash `F` into this reverted commit before pushing. This will give you one commit on `develop` that adds the feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few options:

1. revert the revert

   - pros: this is the approach [recommended by the Git documentation](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt), and it's easy to do
   - cons: uglies the history, which makes it a little more difficult for people to understand how the code evolved over time (e.g., `git blame` will show the revert of the revert instead of the individual commits on the `issue-1` branch)
2. rebase the reverted branch and merge that

   - pros: `git blame` and other history digging tools make it easier to understand the code history
   - cons: looking at the history can be a bit confusing (why are there two seemingly identical sets of commits in the history?  did someone botch a rebase?)
3. edit history: redo your develop branch to remove both commit `M` and commit `R`

   - pros: cleanest end result
   - cons:

     - DANGEROUS if your repository is shared, unless your users are good with Git and you have communicated the plan to everyone
     - difficult to do because Git doesn't have an easy history editing tool:

       - [rebase doesn't make it easy to edit (or edit out) merges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9958215/712605), and the `--preserve-merges` option doesn't work with interactive rebasing so you'll end up flattening the `issue-2` commits into `develop`
       - `filter-branch` is difficult to use

In general the approach I recommend is to revert the revert.  I suggest following these detailed steps:

1. Check out the original bad branch:
   `git checkout issue-1`
2. Merge in the latest commits from the parent branch:
   `git merge --no-ff develop`
3. Revert the revert (where `R` is the SHA1 ID of the revert commit):
   `git revert R`
4. Fix the flaws in the branch.  (You've already done this in commit `F`; for others' sake I'll assume you need to make an additional fix.)
5. TEST TEST TEST
6. Switch back to the parent branch:
   `git checkout develop`
7. Merge in the repaired branch:
   `git merge --no-ff issue-1`

The resulting graph should look like this:

```
              o---o---o issue-2 
             /         \
o---o---o---o---M---R---o-------------o develop
         \     /         \           /
          o---o---F-------o---RR---F2 issue-1
```

It's not pretty, but people should be able to figure out what's going on.