# Change author of git commit that is already merged

Tags: git, github

I've merged a large commit to it's remote origin that is attributed to the wrong author.  I know how to fix this for an unmerged commit, but I'm not sure how this process would work when trying to fix an already merged commit.

I can change the author of the commit locally with:

```
git commit --amend --reset-author
```

This will correct the author of the commit to my local git `user.name` and `user.email`.

However, I'm not sure how to then overwrite the already merged commit with the corrected local commit.  Is there a way to do this without getting into anything overly complicated?  Would `git push -f` overwrite the commit that was merged into master?  Do I have to revert the commit? Not totally sure how to approach this.

Comment: Have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930637/edit-a-merge-commit-with-git-rebase)?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Can you explain how this addresses my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do what they said (`git commit --amend --author="Author Name <email@address.com>"`) and push -f it before someone adds more stuff on top of this (or at least this seemed to work correctly for me on a local repo that I tried it on).